# PHP How to owerwrite object cast to array like: (array) $object with custom function

Tags: php, arrays, object, casting

I need something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    $a = 'A';
    $b = 'B';
    public function __to_array(){
        $r = (array) $this;
        $r['ab'] = 'AB';
        return $r;
    }
};

$x = new MyClass();

$x_as_array = (array) $x;
```

In last line i need not return ['a'=>'A','b'=>'B'] but i need owerwrite this defaul cast to my custom __to_array function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP doesn't have a native implementation of `__toArray()` like they do with `__toString()`.

If you check out the PHP docs for [converting to string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting), you'll see that the `__toString()` magic method is explicitly mentioned as a way to override the default implementation.

However, the documentation regarding [type casting for arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) clearly states what happens when an object is converted to an array without mentioning any magic methods (emphasis mine)

> #### Converting to array
>
> For any of the types integer, float, string, boolean and resource, converting a value to an array results in an array with a single element with index zero and the value of the scalar which was converted. In other words, (array)$scalarValue is exactly the same as array($scalarValue).
>
> **If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose elements are the object's properties**.....
>
> ....

#### Solution

The simple solution is to implement a `->toArray()` method in your class - something many popular collection implementations do (including Laravel's [`Collection`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php))

Another solution that may work is to have your class extend the [`ArrayObject`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) class which allows objects to work as arrays.